# Calculate inverse Matrix of population process

Tags: matrices

I have got the matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0,4 \\ 0,75 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0,8 & 0,8  \end{pmatrix}

Now I need to get the inverse matrix but calculated in steps 
and not generated by the calculator.

I know that the correct solution is:

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4/3 & 0 \\ -2,5 & 0 & 1,25 \\ 2,5 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}

My problem is that there are too many zeroes so 
I fail calculating the inverse matrix.

The way I need to calculate the is to write the original matrix on the left side and the identity matrix on the right:

\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0,4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0,75 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0,8 & 0,8  & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

My Calculation steps:
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0,4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0,75 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0,8 & 0,8  & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

subtraction of the second line and the first:

\begin{pmatrix} 0,75 & 0 & 0,4 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0,75 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0,8 & 0,8  & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

subraction of the second line and the first, 
and subtraction of the third line and the first:

\begin{pmatrix} 0,75 & 0 & 0,4 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0,4  & 1 & -2 & 0\\ 0 & -0,8 & -0,4  & 1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}

subtraction of the third line and the first:

\begin{pmatrix} 0,75 & 0 & 0,4 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0,4  & 1 & -2 & 0\\ 0 & 0,8 & 0,8  & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

while researching I figured out that I have to make at first the elements a21, a31 & a32 have to be set at first to null and then 
a12, a13 & a23.

I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: The too many zeros make the calculation even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix: $ A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4/3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -2,5 & 0 & 1,25 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 2,5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

You have to find the reduced row echelon form of the original matrix (the left half of A) but apply the changes to the whole matrix. Once you get the identity matrix on the left side, the right side of the matrix will be the inverse of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not know what C(A)T means... I have updated my question so perhaps you are able to understand my problem better / way I have to calculate

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to change the matrix into the reverse matrix but as you can see in my updated post I am not able to do that... Do you have a suggestion how to solve my problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: In your second step A11 is -0,75

Comment: You want to get the identity matrix on the left so you have to try and get A11=1, A22=1, A33=1 and all the other coefficients equal 0.

Comment: Here's a tip: If you want A13=0 you can multiply the second line so that A23 = A13 and then subtract the second line to the first one therefore getting A13=0

Answer (score 1):

If

$$ A = \left[\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right] $$

then

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{|A|}\left[\begin{matrix}\left|\begin{matrix} a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{32} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right| & \left|\begin{matrix} a_{13} & a_{12} \\ a_{33} & a_{32} \end{matrix}\right| &  \left|\begin{matrix} a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{22} & a_{23} \end{matrix}\right| \\ \left|\begin{matrix} a_{23} & a_{21} \\ a_{33} & a_{31} \end{matrix}\right| &  \left|\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{13} \\ a_{31} & a_{33} \end{matrix}\right| &  \left|\begin{matrix} a_{13} & a_{11} \\ a_{23} & a_{21} \end{matrix}\right| \\ \left|\begin{matrix} a_{21} & a_{22} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} \end{matrix}\right| &  \left|\begin{matrix} a_{12} & a_{11} \\ a_{32} & a_{31} \end{matrix}\right| &  \left|\begin{matrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{matrix}\right| \end{matrix}\right]. $$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the determinant. There is a simple mnemonic device to memorize this: the determinant in row $i$ and column $j$ is the determinant of the original matrix with that row and column removed.

Calculating the determinants one by one for the matrix you are interested in leads to

$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{0.24}\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 0.32 & 0 \\ -0.6 & 0 & 0.3 \\ 0.6 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right] $$

Comment: I see that your way working with determinants is a quite good one. But for school I need the way I have mentioned in my post